# Page does not exist in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am following this tutorial to create the first `mvc` application ([Create a Movie Database Application)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs).

I already added the create view, but when I click on the Create new link, the page does not exist. Typical `404 error`.

I tried

```
/home/create
/create
/create.aspx
/home/create.aspx
```

I am very newbie at `MVC`, so please dont laugh. :)

EDIT: GLobal .asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

HomeController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Movies.Models;

namespace Movies.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        private LearningEntities _db = new LearningEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(_db.Movies1.ToList());

        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] Movie movieToCreate)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View();
            _db.AddToMovies1(movieToCreate);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: Are you running this in IIS or with the built in Visual Studio web-server (Cassini)?

Comment: btw, in the tutorial the only thing I didnt use was the master page, I did everything without the master page, but I dont think that has something to do with my problem.

Comment: actually is the VS server. but I can change it to try.

Comment: No the VS server should be fine. Can you post your Home controller?

Comment: what version of mvc do you use? I would work with MVC3 and then you don't have .aspx pages, but .cshtml pages

Comment: How did you create the view? Right click on your action and "Add View"? check that your views\home folder have the Create.aspx page in (might be .cshtml if your using razor). Also check your home controller does have a create method.

Comment: I am using MVC 2.  I created the view with right click. And Yes the Create.aspx is there.  THe home controller has a create method, please check the EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Get as well as Post Create method in your controller. You need the following

```
public ActionResult Create() 
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] Movie movieToCreate) 
{ 
 ....
}
```

Edit: The URL to your create view is `/Home/Create`

Answer (score 2):

You dont have a create "get" action.

Basically the create action you have there is for when a form is submitted.

You need this code from the tutorial:

```
// GET: /Home/Create 
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Create you have is for HttpPost which you'll use when you are trying to create an entity. Initially you'll need to have a controller method with HttpGet create method which will let you enter data for a new entity. Also, make sure your view is in Views->home folder.